# Changing an AIX password via script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, passwords, aix

I am trying to change a password of a user via script. I cannot use sudo as there is a feature that requires the user to change the password again if another user changes their password.

AIX is running on the system.

unfortunately, chpasswd is unavailable.

I have expected installed, but I am having trouble with that also.

here is what I thought would work

```
echo "oldpassword\nnewpasswd123\nnewpasswd123" | passwd user
```

However once run the script I am prompted with `please enter user's old password` 
shouldn't they all be echoed in?

I am a beginner with shell scripting and this has been baffled.

Comment: Note that AIX isn't Linux; you should update your question to clarify which you are asking about.

Comment: @rakslice - Changed the title.

Answer (score 76):

You can try:

`echo "USERNAME:NEWPASSWORD" | chpasswd`

Comment: For it to work for me I had to change it to: `echo "USERNAME:NEWPASSWORD" | sudo chpasswd` when executing through a non sudo parent script

Comment: `chpasswd` to me seems like the right answer.  Worked for me setting up a Docker image.  I like the following (in bash) to avoid the 'echo' noise: 

`chpasswd <<<"$USERNAME:$PASSWORD"`

Answer (score 21):

Use **GNU** `passwd` *stdin* flag.

From the `man` page:

> ```
>    --stdin
>           This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new password from standard input, which can be a pipe.
> ```

**NOTE:** Only for **root** user.

**Example**

```
$ adduser foo 
$ echo "NewPass" |passwd foo --stdin
Changing password for user foo.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Alternatively you can use `expect`, this simple code will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn passwd foo
expect "password:"
send "Xcv15kl\r"
expect "Retype new password:"
send "Xcv15kl\r"
interact
```

**Results**

```
$ ./passwd.xp 
spawn passwd foo
Changing password for user foo.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Comment: yeah i tried that too: 

`"echo oldpassword\nnewpasswd123\nnewpasswd123" | passwd --stdin user`

i get passwd: illegal option -- -

Comment: I su'd to root an i got the same "illegal option -- -"

Comment: seems like it, a lot of people's suggestions look like they should work, but don't.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04: `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'`

Comment: Newer versions do not support --stdin (e.g. openSUSE Leap 42.1; it worked in 12.1 but doesn't work anymore).

Comment: this `expect` example do not work with the most locales. Maybe set it to `C`?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other suggestions, you can also achieve this using a [HEREDOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

In your immediate case, this might look like:

```
$ /usr/bin/passwd root <<EOF
test
test
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

You need echo -e for the newline characters to take affect

you wrote

```
echo "oldpassword\nnewpasswd123\nnewpasswd123" | passwd user
```

you should try

```
echo -e "oldpassword\nnewpasswd123\nnewpasswd123" | passwd user
```

more than likely, you will not need the oldpassword\n portion of that command, you should just need the two new passwords.  Don't forget to use single quotes around exclamation points!

```
echo -e "new"'!'"passwd123\nnew"'!'"passwd123" | passwd user
```

Comment: What if the password contains a "\n"? Such as `my@secret\npasword123` ?

Comment: Great answer! Worked fine for me on Ubuntu. I had a similar requiremnt, but for first time setting (and not changing) a user's password. The mention of \n character along with -e option to seperate out the reply to the 2 password prompts really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

> echo -e "newpasswd123\nnnewpasswd123" | passwd user

Comment: I have the following code in a bash script and it works fine :


`useradd -s /bin/bash -g www-data -d /var/www/$vhost $Name;
echo -e "$sshPasswd\n$sshPasswd" | passwd $Name;
id $Name`

Answer (score 3):

Just this

```
passwd <<EOF
oldpassword
newpassword
newpassword
EOF
```

Actual output from ubuntu machine (sorry no AIX available to me):

```
user@host:~$ passwd <<EOF
oldpassword
newpassword
newpassword
EOF

Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
user@host:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is from : [Script to change password on linux servers over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236699/script-to-change-password-on-linux-servers-over-ssh)

The script below will need to be saved as a file (eg `./passwdWrapper`) and made executable (`chmod u+x ./passwdWrapper)`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#wrapper to make passwd(1) be non-interactive
#username is passed as 1st arg, passwd as 2nd

set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set serverid [lindex $argv 2]
set newpassword [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh $serverid passwd
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect "UNIX password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "password:"
send "$newpassword\r"
expect "password:"
send "$newpassword\r"
expect eof
```

Then you can run `./passwdWrapper $user $password $server $newpassword` which will actually change the password.

Note: This requires that you install `expect` on the machine from which you will be running the command. (`sudo apt-get install expect`) The script works on CentOS 5/6 and Ubuntu 14.04, but if the prompts in `passwd` change, you may have to tweak the `expect` lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the script... 

#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter username:"
read username
echo "Please enter the new password:"
read -s password1
echo "Please repeat the new password:"
read -s password2

# Check both passwords match
if [ $password1 != $password2 ]; then
echo "Passwords do not match"
 exit    
fi

# Does User exist?
id $username &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "$username exists... changing password."
else
echo "$username does not exist - Password could not be updated for $username"; exit 
fi

# Change password
echo -e "$password1\n$password1" | passwd $username
```

Refer the link below as well...

```
http://www.putorius.net/2013/04/bash-script-to-change-users-password.html
```

Comment: thanks, but it's just this line `echo -e "$password1\n$password1" | passwd $username` that my system doesn't like

Comment: Did you provided the new password here?

echo -e "$password1\n$password1" | passwd $username

Answer (score 1):

You can try

**LINUX**

> echo password | passwd username --stdin

**UNIX**

> echo username:password | chpasswd -c

If you dont use "-c" argument, you need to change password next time.

Comment: `echo username:password | chpasswd -c` throws error

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ansible, and set the sudo rights in it, then you can easily use this script.  If you're wanting to script something like this, it means you need to do it on more than one system.  Therefore, you should try to automate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked in a vagrant VM:

```
sudo /usr/bin/passwd root <<EOF
12345678
12345678
EOF
```

Comment: This is still a simple answer if you can get over the word sudo and add the old password on a line.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf "oldpassword/nnewpassword/nnewpassword" | passwd user
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import string
import smtplib
import sys
import os
from subprocess import call
import socket

user = sys.argv[1]
receivers = ["%s@domain.com" %user]

'''This will generate a 30 character random password'''
def genrandpwd():
        return  ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + string.punctuation) for _ in range(30))

def change_passwd(user, password):
        p = os.popen("/usr/bin/passwd %s" %user, "w")
        p.write(password)
        p.write("\n")
        p.write(password)
    p.close()

def chage(user):
        agepasswd = call(["/usr/bin/chage", "-d", "0", "%s" %user])

def mailpwd(user, password):
        sender = "admin@%s" %socket.gethostname()
        subj = "!!!IMPORTANT!!!, Unix password changed for user %s" %user
        text = "The password for the %s user has changed, the new password is:\n\n %s \n\n Note: The system will force to change the password upon initial login. Please use the password provided in the mail as your current password and type the password of your choice as the New password" %(user, password)
        message = message = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subj, text)
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mailrelay-server.domain.com')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        smtpObj.quit()

def main():
        newpwd = genrandpwd()
        change_passwd(user, newpwd)
        chage(user)
        mailpwd(user, newpwd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: This script can be run in a linux machine. You can modify certain things according to your environment like mail relay server or change the limit in the password characters etc.